# How do you recruit Darkrai in Pokemon Mystery Dungeon: Explorers of Sky?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-mystery-dungeon-explorers

I have defeated Darkrai and read on Wikipedia that he/it can be found in various areas. Where are these areas? Can he be encountered in any area, or in certain multiple dungeons?  If he is found in certain dungeons, then which ones, and on what floor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Darkrai in those dungeons:

- Mystic Forest 13F
- Crevice Cave Deepest Part B2F
- Miracle Sea B3F
- Mt. Practice B17F
- Sky Fissure B14F

But you must have the Secret Slab or Enigma Part in your bag.

[Source](http://serebii.net/dungeonsky/legendary.shtml)